# Updating web.config to change aspnetdb to own database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf-ria-services, aspnetdb

I am working on a web application in which i have to add some authorization and so i do have a database ASPNETDB.MDF and i want my application to use WATERINFO.MDF from SQL server.

I have upadted WATERINFO.MDF with all schema and data using aspnet_regsql.exe

At present my web.config file of silverlight app is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
      <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <roleManager enabled="true"/>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".AuthorizationSample_ASPXAUTH" />
    </authentication>

    <profile>
      <properties>
        <add name="FriendlyName"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
          type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now to change it to WATERINFO.MDF i need to update config file

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=COMPLEX\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=waterinfo;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

      </connectionStrings>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
          <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>



      <system.web>

        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DPISqlRoleProvider">
          <providers>
            <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="DPI" name="DPISqlRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>

          </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </httpModules>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />



        <authentication mode="Forms">

        </authentication>


        <membership defaultProvider="DPISqlMembershipProvider">

          <providers>
            <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="DPI" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
     passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="DPISqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>

          </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
          <properties>
            <add name="FriendlyName"/>
          </properties>
        </profile>

      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
              type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </modules>
      </system.webServer>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

I updated these changes in my web.config file but was not able to change the database to new one.

Also i know i can use `<remove "LocalSqlServer">` but that's now good for production purpose

Please suggest what change should i make in my web.config file.

Thanks

Reply

Comment: Changed title and content, as you are trying to change the settings for this web site who hosts the Silverlight package. It is still a web site, and changing its setting has nothing to do with Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, there were some connection string errors and some other minutes changes... I need to update Web.Config file as such

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.serviceModel">
      <section name="domainServices" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServicesSection, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="My Connection Details"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>


  <system.web>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DPISqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" applicationName="DPI" name="DPISqlRoleProvider"
 type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>

      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />



    <authentication mode="Forms">

    </authentication>


    <membership defaultProvider="DPISqlMembershipProvider">

      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="DPI" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed"
 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
 passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" name="DPISqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>

      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <add name="FriendlyName"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
          type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the connectionStrings tag below configSections. configSections must be the first, as stated in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7%28vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi did changed it and updated the question. But its not getting connected